# How to save downloaded data from an API to RAM in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a really simple app in Flutter, but I have a problem with state management.

Here's the video of what I have. Link: https://streamable.com/ir3ztr

The video shows my application, but when I switch a screen using Bottom Navigation Bar, the data loads again and again from the API. I don't want that. I want the once downloaded data to be saved in RAM and not being downloaded again from the API. Is that possible? I heard about Provider, but I don't know how to use that in my case.

Is there anyone who can help me?

My code:

### World

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter_placeholder_textlines/flutter_placeholder_textlines.dart';
import '../../models/world.dart';
import '../../data/world_service.dart';

class WorldScreenAndroid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WorldScreenAndroidState createState() => _WorldScreenAndroidState();
}

class _WorldScreenAndroidState extends State<WorldScreenAndroid> {
  Future<World> futureWorld;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureWorld = fetchWorld();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FutureBuilder<World> (
        future: futureWorld,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.public),
                  title: Text('coronavirus_cases').tr(context: context),
                  subtitle: Text(NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data.cases).toString())
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.public),
                  title: Text('deaths').tr(context: context),
                  subtitle: Text(NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data.deaths).toString())
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.public),
                  title: Text('recovered').tr(context: context),
                  subtitle: Text(NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data.recovered).toString())
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }

          return ListView(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.public),
                  title: Text('coronavirus_cases').tr(context: context),
                  subtitle: PlaceholderLines(
                    count: 1,
                    animate: true,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    minWidth: 0.10,
                    maxWidth: 0.50,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.public),
                  title: Text('deaths').tr(context: context),
                  subtitle: PlaceholderLines(
                    count: 1,
                    animate: true,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    minWidth: 0.10,
                    maxWidth: 0.50,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.public),
                  title: Text('recovered').tr(context: context),
                  subtitle: PlaceholderLines(
                    count: 1,
                    animate: true,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    minWidth: 0.10,
                    maxWidth: 0.50,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ) 
    );
  }
}
```

### Countries

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import '../../models/country.dart';
import '../../data/countries_service.dart';

class CountriesScreenAndroid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountriesScreenAndroidState createState() => _CountriesScreenAndroidState();
}

class _CountriesScreenAndroidState extends State<CountriesScreenAndroid> {
  Future<List<Country>> futureCountries;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureCountries = fetchCountries();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: futureCountries,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                TextField(),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                      final List<String> _countriesAllArgs = [
                        NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data[index].cases),
                        NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data[index].todayCases),
                        NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data[index].active),
                        NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data[index].deaths),
                        NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data[index].todayDeaths),
                        NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data[index].recovered),
                        NumberFormat('#,###,###', 'en_US').format(snapshot.data[index].critical)
                      ];

                      return Card(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                snapshot.data[index].country,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                              Text(
                                'countries_all',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                                ),
                              ).tr(args: _countriesAllArgs),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      );
                    }
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }

          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `provider` is a dependency injection library, not a state management one, and probably also state management is not handy for what are you looking to accomplish here. Try to look for caching API requests in Flutter, this will go more along the line of what are you looking to accomplish here.

Comment: There are many possibilities to do what you want. A http cache as @StefanoSaitta said. You case also use a Provider to store your data in the parent widget. You can store in database with sqlite... and more

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to keep the loaded data in a parent widget, not in the widget your switching.
Have you considered using the BLOC framework?
In that case, you could nicely sepearte Business Logic from UI code and keep the loaded data in the bloc.

In detail have a blocProvider on top, wrapping your app.
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocprovider

Alternatively, but be carefull with the handling though, you can just create an object, anywhere outside of any widget, and access it from anywhere.

```
class Data {
  List<String> stringsLoadedFromWeb;
}

Data data = Data();
```

// from anywhere else, where you import the above file

```
data.stringsLoadedFromWeb = ...
```